# Application referencing library fails to find interface within another library

Tags: java, android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I have a strange problem and I cannot figure out regarding libraries and dependency.

I have an app called `MyApp`. Which calls a class called `MyLib1Class1`.

`MyLib1Class1` implements `MyLib2Interface` and `MyLib1Class` calls `MyLib2Class` and passes the interface to it.

`MyLib1...` and `MyLib2...` are two separate library projects that are published to a local Maven repository.

`MyLib1` has the dependency in the gradle file to `MyLib2`

`MyApp` has the dependency of `MyLib1`

The two libraries compile fine.

When I compile `MyApp` I get the error:

> class file for `MyLib2Interface` not found

Note, that the app only reference MyLib1 and MyLib1 reference MyLib2 which contains the interface.

If I add the dependency of `MyLib2` into `MyApp` it works but I don't want to have to do this, I want to be able to include the dependency of `MyLib1` which automatically contains `MyLib2` without needing to reference it again in the app.